# Spring Boot Security OncePerRequestFilter behavior for permitted URLs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, controller, config

I have created a test Spring Boot application with Spring Security dependency added.  I created the following configuration for Spring Security:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService service;
    @Autowired
    private InvaildUserAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;
    @Autowired
    private SecurityFilter securityFilter;
    

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authManager(HttpSecurity http) 
      throws Exception {
        return http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
          .userDetailsService(service)
          .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder)
          .and()
          .build();
    }
    
    
  @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/register","/confirmemail/*","/test").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
        .and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(securityFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        ;
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Question:  When I have in my security configuration given the url permitAll, should it not bypass the security filters? Why then does it pass through the OncePerRequestFilter.

Here is the stack trace of the error I get:

```
io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureException: JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted.
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:354) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:481) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parseClaimsJws(DefaultJwtParser.java:541) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at com.fbh.erp10.utility.JwtUtil.getUserNameFromJwtToken(JwtUtil.java:126) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.fbh.erp10.config.SecurityFilter.doFilterInternal(SecurityFilter.java:46) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:350) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0-M6.jar:6.0.0-M6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0-M6.jar:6.0.0-M6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0-M6.jar:6.0.0-M6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:350) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0-M6.jar:6.0.0-M6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0-M6.jar:6.0.0-M6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0-M6.jar:6.0.0-M6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:350) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0-M6.jar:6.0.0-M6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilterInternal(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0-M6.jar:6.0.0-M6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:350) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0-M6.jar:6.0.0-M6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0-M6.jar:6.0.0-M6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:350) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0-M6.jar:6.0.0-M6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0-M6.jar:6.0.0-M6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:350) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0-M6.jar:6.0.0-M6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0-M6.jar:6.0.0-M6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0-M6.jar:6.0.0-M6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:351) ~[spring-web-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:356) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:867) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1760) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar:10.0.22]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: No it shouldn't. `permitAll` means everyone authenticated (anonymously or otherwise) can access it. If you do't want any filter applied you need to to configure that differently.